# Dropdown list with Adodb query

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create the dropdown list with the results from my query. I'm looking for help please because I don't know how to display this results on the list.

The exemple of the list:

[image]

My query is :

```
 'DROPDOWN LIST

  Private Sub cb_gest_Change()
  If Not FSD.cb_gest.MatchFound And FSD.cb_gest <> "" Then
  MsgBox "Saisie impossible, le gestionnaire n'existe pas !", , "Contrôle 
  Gestionnaire"
  FSD.cb_gest = ""
  Else
  FSD.Cells(29, COL_DATA) = FSD.cb_gest
  End If
  End Sub

  'DROPDOWN LIST

  Sub init_combo()
  Dim Resultat As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim Requete As String
  FSD.cb_gest.Clear
  Requete = "select lb_gestion from DB_GESTIONNAIRE "
  Requete = Requete + "WHERE (d_deb_valid <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) OR d_deb_valid IS 
  NULL) AND (d_fin_valid >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) OR d_fin_valid IS NULL)"
  Requete = Requete + " ORDER BY LB_GESTION"
  Set Resultat = New ADODB.Recordset
  Resultat.ActiveConnection = oBase
  Resultat.Source = Requete
  Resultat.Open
  While Not Resultat.EOF
  FSD.cb_gest.AddItem Resultat!lb_gestion
  Resultat.MoveNext
  Wend
  If FSD.Cells(29, COL_DATA).Value <> "" Then
  FSD.cb_gest = FSD.Cells(29, COL_DATA).Value
  Else
  FSD.Cells(29, COL_DATA).Value = ""
  End If
  End Sub
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Is this a Dropdown control or Data Validation for a cell?

Comment: @FunThomas It's a Data Validation, I would like to click on the list to choose the option. Thank you for asking.

Comment: @FunThomas I improved my code in main message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a different, codeless approach:

- Add a new sheet to the host document / workbook
- Import the external data from the "Data" Ribbon tab (select "From SQL Server")

  - Excel creates a `ListObject` table backed with a `QueryTable` object that uses a `WorkbookConnection` that can be configured to automatically refresh on open, or left alone as a one-time pull.
- Select the `produit` column in the ListObject/table; Excel highlights the entire column content and leaves the heading un-selected.
- From the "Formulas" Ribbon tab, click the "Define Name" command in the "Defined Names" group.

  - Name the range `ProductsList`, verify it refers to `TableName[produit]` so that it automatically grows and shrinks to fit the column contents.
- Change the data validation list to `=ProductsList`.
- Hide the worksheet housing the query and table, if needed.

No code needed, and the validation list will always keep up with the query results as they are refreshed.

---

Side note, the query appears to be making inefficient cross-joins, and at least one of them is a where-join that can be expressed as an inner join. Are you sure the query is yielding the expected records (I'm suspecting it's yielding a ton of duplicates, depending on how many records exist in the cross-joined tables)?

```sql
SELECT prod.cd_produit AS produit 
FROM db_dossier sousc, db_produit prod, db_protocole proto, db_tiers tiers, db_personne pers
WHERE sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' AND sousc.lp_etat_doss NOT IN ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') AND sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit
```

Instinct would be to remove the tables we're not selecting or filtering anything from - if this query produces the same expected output, then assuming primary and foreign keys are defined I believe its execution plan would be more efficient:

```sql
SELECT prod.cd_produit AS produit 
FROM db_dossier AS sousc
INNER JOIN db_produit AS prod ON sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit
WHERE sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' AND sousc.lp_etat_doss NOT IN ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY')
```

Comment: is it possible to create the list with code ? I improved the code in my main question. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Marie yes of course, but you'd be reinventing the wheel and making your life a complete misery by using a ComboBox control instead of data validation... especially for a query that isn't parameterized. Consider using Excel's built-in data validation feature for this: you get an in-cell dropdown and input and error messages, without needing a single line of code for any of it. If you insist on using a `Recordset`, see [Range.CopyFromRecordset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.CopyFromRecordset) to avoid iterating it and use a `Range` for the combobox source.

Comment: @MathieuGuidon thank you, so if I would like to use the ComboBox, I need to use the Range.CopyFromRecordset ? Do you know some site where I can read about the creating of ComBox please, I never used it before. Thank you very much !